# How can I ensure both levels of a binary variable are represented in every cluster?

Tags: clustering, k-means

Let's say I have some continuous variables and a binary treatment indicator. I want to cluster my observations based on the variables while ensuring that each cluster contains at least one member of each treatment level. Is there a variant of k-means clustering or another principled clustering algorithm that can be used to cluster the observations while satisfying this constraint?

One approach I thought about was to do regular k-means, and if any cluster lacked a member of one treatment group, re-classify a single unit from another cluster to belong to that cluster (knowing this would degrade the cluster performance). However, I'm still stuck on how to do so in a principled way so as to minimize the within-cluster distances.

I know constrained k-means can constrain the sizes of the clusters, but I'm not sure of an implementation that can put constraints on their composition.

Comment: An *ad hoc* method would be to add a large penalty to the objective function whenever any cluster is homogeneous.  This *might* produce good solutions, so if your clustering is exploratory in nature, that could be OK.  The general problem is likely to exhibit many nearly equivalent local minima, which could make finding the global minimum quite challenging.

Comment: Assuming we have a single binary indicator, I would do a two-stage approach: Stage 1: Construct 1-to-1 pairs between treated and untreated subjects (standard greedy nearest neighbour matching without replacement). Stage 2: Cluster the pairs. Option 2A: Make surrogate pairs based on the numerical average of the pairs' continuous variables. Option 2B: Stare into the recent clustering literature abyss with something like [*Clustering-driven Deep Embedding with Pairwise Constraints*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08457) and use pairwise constraints formally. :)

Comment: (I suppose we can also use other matching methods.) The procedure above will not guarantee that all clusters have at least one treated variable especially if some of the control instances are very dissimilar to the treatment ones. I view this as a plus but I suppose it can be a problem. In that case, I would replace Stage 1 with a random pairing and then do either 2A or 2B. Effectively do random initialisations for the clustering pairs. $k$-means already does random initialisation so nobody should be shocked at it. Standard clustering metrics apply, and no new objective functions.